# Not able to create multiple custom db tables on activation of wp Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i am unable to create multiple custom tables in db on activation of my wordpress plugin  it creates only the last table like mentioned in this code is "Bookmark" instead of creating all tables (user,field,visibility,notify) etc

```
function your_plugin_options_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    //global $your_db_name;
    $uservar = $wpdb->prefix . 'user';
    $fieldvar = $wpdb->prefix . 'field';
    $visibilitytypevar = $wpdb->prefix . 'visibily';
    $notificationvar = $wpdb->prefix . 'notification';
    $jobtypevar = $wpdb->prefix . 'jobtype';
    $bookmarkvar = $wpdb->prefix . 'bookmark';
   // $profiledatavar = $wpdb->prefix . 'profiledata';
    //$employeevar = $wpdb->prefix . 'employee';
 //echo "some";
    // create the ECPT metabox database table
    //if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$yourtable'") != $yourtable) 
    //{
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $uservar . " (
        `u_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `u_name` varchar(30) ,
        `u_phonenumber` int(20) ,
        `u_email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        `u_password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (u_id)
         );";
          $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $fieldvar . " (
         `f_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
         `f_title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (f_id)
         );";

         $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $visibilitytypevar . " (
         `v_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
         `v_type` bool NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (v_id)
         );";

         $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $notificationvar . " (
         `n_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
         `u_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (n_id)
         );";

         $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $jobtypevar . " (
         `jt_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
         `jt_title` varchar(30),
         PRIMARY KEY (jt_id)
         );";

          $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $bookmarkvar . " (
         `bm_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
         `u_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
         `bm_title` varchar(30),
         PRIMARY KEY (bm_id)
         );";


        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
    }

//}
// run the install scripts upon plugin activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'your_plugin_options_install');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are overriding your `$sql` variable. 
Just use dbDelta function after every query. 
like below format.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

// your first query
$sql = '...'; 
dbDelta($sql);

// your second query
$sql = '...'; 
dbDelta($sql);

.
.
.


// your nth query
$sql = '...'; 
dbDelta($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens, because in your function, you are always rewriting your `$sql` variable, before you execute them. This is why only the last is executed.

After every `$sql` definition, run the query.

```
//define the query
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `firsttable` ....";
//Run the query
dbDelta($sql); //If this is what is running the query.
//Another table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `secondtable` ....";
//Run the new query
dbDelta($sql); //If this is what is running the query.
```

Answer (score 0):

if `dbDelta($sql);` runs your sql you have to add this line uder each sql statement to excute it

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

for first query wright `$sql = "your query text goes here"`,

and for all next queries `$sql .= "your query text goes here"`